# Is it ok to say "I want to take showers / 2 showers now"?

Tags: word-usage

In [the dictionary](https://www.ldoceonline.com/dictionary/shower),

> shower: an act of washing your body while standing under a shower
>
> I need a shower.
>
> take a shower
>
> Nick rolled out of bed and took a shower.
>
> have a shower especially British English
>
> Mary loves having a hot shower after she’s been swimming.

Most people say "**take a shower**".

My question is that

**Could we say:**

*I want to take showers now*

*I want to take 3 showers now*

*I take 2 showers every day*

*I take showers every day*

Comment: Yes we could say any of those.

Answer (score 2):

To **take showers** means to engage in the practice of taking showers as your habitual or regular form of bathing.

> Now that my broken leg is healed, and the cast is off, I can take
>   showers again.

Normally we use the present simple to refer to such practice or habit. Thus:

> I *shower* every day.
>
> I don't like sitting in the tub. I *take* showers.
>
> I don't like sitting in the tub. I *shower* instead.

You can specify a number of showers.

> What with soccer practice in the afternoon, and gym class in the
>   morning, he takes two, sometimes three, showers a day.

Answer (score 1):

No matter how intensely or how many times you wash yourself while standing under the shower, that's just one shower, not two or three.

If you wanted to say that you took two showers, you would probably need at least a short gap between them.  Otherwise, people would count it as a single shower.

Most people would regard your sentences "I want to take showers now" and "I want to take 3 showers now" as close to nonsensical.

You might say that someone took two showers if, shortly after leaving the bathroom, they changed their mind and went back in and showered again.

Your sentences "I take 2 showers every day" and "I take showers every day" are absolutely fine.  (Most people will assume that they refer to one shower in the morning and a second shower in the evening or in the afternoon.)

Comment: I have no idea why it got 1 vote down. I didn't.